# NameError in Django simple search

Tags: python, django, search, foreign-keys

I have a simple search in my Django project. I want to search through documents using their type and part of factory info in addition to search by name.
Here is my **models.py:**

```
class Docs(models.Model):
    Date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Type = models.ForeignKey(DocTypes)
    Part = models.ForeignKey(Parts)
    Link = models.FileField(upload_to='Docs/%Y/%m/%d')
class Parts(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Name)
class DocTypes(models.Model):
    Type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Type)
```

My **forms.py:**

```
class DocsSearchForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Docs
        fields = [ 'Name', 'Type', 'Part']
```

And this is part of my **views.py**, if no search was done then all documents are given

```
def showdocs(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocsSearchForm(request.POST)
        documents = Docs.objects.filter(Name__contains=request.POST['Name']|
                                          Type==request.POST['Type']|
                                          Part==request.POST['Part'])
    else:
        form = DocsSearchForm()
        documents = Docs.objects.all()
    return render(
        request,
        'showdocs.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form':form}
```

So, the problem is the following: if I try to use a search then I have 
**NameError at /showdocs
name 'Type' is not defined.**
POST values are:Part  '1', Name 'Example', Type '1'.

If I delete

```
 Type==request.POST['Type']|
 Part==request.POST['Part']
```

then search by name works well. So I have a guess that problem is about searching by foreign key values, but have no ideas more. Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the line with this

```
Docs.objects.filter(Name__contains=request.POST['Name'],
                    Type=request.POST['Type'],
                    Part=request.POST['Part']
                    )
```

It seems you have misunderstood the syntax. I don't know why you are trying to use `|` operator here.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Django filters work. You can't `|` them because they are not actually expressions, just keyword arguments. In this case, correct syntax would be:

```
Docs.objects.filter(
  Name__contains=request.POST['Name'],
  Type_Type=request.POST['Type'],
  Part_Name=request.POST['Part'],
)`
```